# Hibernate deletion issue with a bidirectional association

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA (1.7.2-RELEASE) in combination with Hibernate (4.3.8.Final) and MySQL (5.5). I want to manage two entities in a bidirectional assosciation. The save and update of the enties works fine, but the deletion doesn't work.

```
@Entity
public class Beacon extends AbstractEntity {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "beacon", cascade = ALL)
private Set<Comment> comments;

/**
 * @return the comments
 */
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

/**
 * @param comments the comments to set
 */
public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Comment extends AbstractEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "beacon_id")
private Beacon beacon;

public Beacon getBeacon() {
    return beacon;
}

public void setBeacon(Beacon beacon) {
    this.beacon = beacon;
}
}
```

Having a beacon with comments stored in the database, I want to delete the comment but it doesn't work. I don't get an exception but the entity is still present in the database.

This is my unit test:

```
 @Test
public void deleteWithStrategyCheck() {

    Beacon beacon = this.beaconRepository.save(createBeacon());

    Comment comment = this.commentRepository.save(createEntity());
    comment.setBeacon(beacon);
    comment = this.commentRepository.save(comment);

    this.commentRepository.delete(comment.getId());

    assertThat(this.commentRepository.exists(comment.getId())).isFalse();
    assertThat(this.beaconRepository.exists(beacon.getId())).isTrue();
    assertThat(this.beaconRepository.findOne(beacon.getId()).getComments()).doesNotContain(comment);
}
```

If I delete the comment via a sql statement it works.

Comment: How do you know that the entity is still in the database? Is the test transactional? Does it rollback at the end?

Comment: I am using the mysql shell to check the entities in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `orphanRemoval = true` to your `@OneToMany` mappings, and remove the Comment from the parrent beacon.

If you delete the Comment without removing it from the parrent collection you should actually get the exception (unless you are not using InnoDB storage engine, (and ou should)).

```
beacon.getComments().remove(comment),
```

will do the work then. (with orphanRemoval you don't need to call EM.remove(comment). Without it, you need to remove the comment from the collection and call EM.remove(comment).

Comment: If OP would check hibernate detail logs, he would find `delete from comment where id = ? was aborted.` cause when the em is auto-flushing he finds that comment is still inside the bacon's comment colletction.